# Search table after jQuery set the value

Tags: jquery, html

I made 2 tables  ID='table_1' and ID='table_4'. When I click on the row in the table_1 I want jQuery to takes cell value of the column Item and set that value to the search input text box of the table_4. Everything seems to work fine but one thing is missing. So when I click on the row in the table_1 jQuery gets the item cell value and set it up successfully to the table_4 search input text box but doesn't update table result. Looks like input value change every time when I click on the other row in the table_1 but table_4 does not filter results according to the value in the text box search.

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


 window.jQuery(function($) {
   $('#table_1').on({
     click: function(e) {

        var data = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq( 1 )').text();
        $("#table_4_filter .form-control").val(data).trigger("change");

     }
   }, 'td');
});

</script>
```

I tried few solutions that I found here according to the trigger and change event but didn't help. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem.

[image: Tables at my website]

Comment: I assume that if you write something manually in that input, the table filter the results, right? Maybe the filter is triggered for `keyup`or `keydown` events instead of `change`? Have you try triggering that events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table looks like one from datatables.net. In this case, don't update the search box directly, instead use the api:

```
$('#table_4').DataTable().search(data).draw();
```

The `.search(newfilter)` will fill your search field, the chained `.draw()` will update your table view.